# How to redirect to a route after sweet alert 'OK' button has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, sweetalert

`swalService.success('You're all set!', 'Check your status...')`

How do I get access to the 'ok' button that shows up and its onClick method to redirect to a route with react router?

This is the class I've created for sweetalert

```
import swal from 'sweetalert'

class SwalService {
  success(title, text) {
    return swal(title, text, 'success')
  }
}

export const swalService = new SwalService()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the returned promise.

```
swal(title, text, 'success')
 .then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
   if(result) {
     // ok click
   } else {
     // not clicked
   }
 });
```